# Scraping dynamic information in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to use an xpath to scrape a figure I need on [this website](http://www.myfxbook.com/community/outlook/EURUSD)

I need these two numbers

[image]

---

So far I'm having no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried and describe exactly how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be xPath? You can get it with:

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("http://www.myfxbook.com/community/outlook/EURUSD")
page %>% html_nodes("#leftColumn td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
```